# Laravel 8 Debugger code Conflict with JavaScript DOM Element. I am using barryvdh/laravel-debugbar library

Tags: javascript, laravel-8

I'm working on a Laravel for the back-end and JavaScript in blade for front-end interactivity. However, I'm encountering an issue where it seems that my Laravel-debigger code is conflicting with my JavaScript DOM manipulation, causing unexpected behavior or errors.

Here's

```
    function printLabel(flag_finish = null) {


      

        //***  Flag Removals Start ***//
        // localStorage.removeItem('consolidate_status');
        // localStorage.removeItem('begin_process_flag');
        //***  Flag Removals End ***//


        var missing_count = missing_pkgs.length;


        var shelf_id = $("#shelf_location").find(":selected").val();
        var shelf_location = $("#shelf_location").find(":selected").text();


        if (shelf_id != "") {

            var html = "<!DOCTYPE html>";
            var printPreview = window.open('', '_top');
            var printDocument = printPreview.document;
            printDocument.open();

            html += '<head>' +
                '<style>' +
                '</style>' +
                '</head>';

            html += '<body style="font-family: arial; padding: 0px;margin: 0px;">';


            html +=
                '<div style="height:60px;width:384px;">' +
                '<div><img style="height:30px;width:350px" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ $barcode }}" alt=""></div>' +
                '<div><span style="font-family:Times New Roman;padding-top:0px;font-size:250%;font-weight: bold;">GS-{{ $consolidation->original_request_id }}</span></div>';

            if (missing_count) {

                html +=
                    '<div><span style="font-family:Times New Roman;padding-top:0px;font-size:100%;font-weight: bold;">Loc:' +
                    localStorage.getItem('location') + ' (Incomplete)</span></div>' +
                    '<div><span style="font-family:Times New Roman;padding-top:0px;font-size:50%;font-weight: bold;">' +
                    missing_count + ' Package(s) Missing</span></div>';

                localStorage.removeItem('location');

            }

            html += '</div>';



            html += '</body>' +
                '</html>';

            printDocument.write(html);
            printDocument.close();
            printPreview.print();

            window.location.replace("{{ route('employee.consolidate.index') }}");

        } else {
            responseMsg('error', "{{ asset('images/error-123.png') }}", "Please choose shelf location");
        }
    }
```

[image]